# OSError: Only one use of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am creating a basic chat application, and I am using socket io, But when I load it using server it shows this error
***OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted***

application.py

```
    from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET_KEY'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(message):
    print('Message :' + message)
    send(message, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat Room</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var scoket = io.connect(location.protocol +  '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port );
                socket.on('connect', function(){
                    socket.send('User has connected');
                });

                socket.on('message', function(message){
                    $("messages").append('<li'+message+'<li>');
                    console.log("Recieved message")
                });

                $('sendbutton').on('click',function(){
                    socket.send($('#mymessage').val());
                    $('#mymessage').val('');
                });

            });
        </script>
        <ul id ='messages'></ul>
        <input type="text" id = 'mymessage'>
        <button id = 'sendbutton'>Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The message means what it says. Your code is trying to open a port that is already in use by something else. Most likely a previous version of your program that failed and didn't shut the socket down properly.

Comment: How do I shut it down?